# VS 2015 install of PostSharp 4.1.21 Fails

Tags: visual-studio-2015, postsharp

I get the following error in my activitylog for VS2015 after I've installed PostSharp. Any thoughts on what to do?

`` Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: An exception was thrown while initializing part "PostSharp.VisualStudio.Package.IdeService". ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at PostSharp.VisualStudio.Package.IdeService..ctor() in c:\src\PostSharp-4.1\UserInterface\PostSharp.VisualStudio.Package.Shared\IdeService.cs:line 25 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.b__0() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportElement(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import, RuntimeExport export, Func3 lazyFactory) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportSite(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.<CreateValue>b__10_0(RuntimeImport import) at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator2.MoveNext() at System.Linq.Buffer1..ctor(IEnumerable1 source) at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable1 source) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.CreateValue() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.Create() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass15_0.<GetExportedValueHelper>b__0() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.DelegateServices.<>c__DisplayClass2_01.b__0() at System.Lazy1.CreateValue() at System.Lazy1.LazyInitValue() at System.Lazy1.get_Value() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.InvokeMatchingFactories[TExtensionInstance,TExtensionFactory,TMetadataView](IEnumerable1 lazyFactories, Func`2 getter, IContentType dataContentType, Object errorSource) ``

Comment: Please, what is exact version of Visual Studio you are using? What is the edition? Was there any inner exception?

Comment: I am using VS 2015 released version, not the RC.  It is enterprise edition, and the only indication of an error was a message stating an error occurred and that pointed me to a file called ActivityLog.xml in %appdata%\microsoft\visualstudio\14.0.

Comment: Thanks. This seems like a known (non-deterministic) bug in PostSharp VSiX. The fix is ready and it is going to be released next week. Are you currently able to use PostSharp with VS2015?

Comment: Nope, every time VS2015 loads, I get the activitylog.xml error and I can't see PostSharp anywhere.  Very frustrating because I REALLY was looking to use the Log tracing function...

Comment: Disable the extension and set MSBuild property PostSharpSkipVsxCheck to true.

Comment: @Jakub: OK, I disabled the extension, but I'm sorry, but I don't know how to set the MSBuild property you mentioned to true.  I'm working on a VS2015 solution file with a single windows forms C# project within it. can you explain how to do that?

Comment: Unload the project, edit csproj file, add `<PostSharpSkipVsxCheck>True</PostSharpSkipVsxCheck>` somewhere in first PropertyGroup, reload project.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug fixed in PostSharp 4.1.23 (4.2.8) and higher versions.